# Form authentication - Need event that should execute only once after form authentication happens

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

As I am working on `Form Authentication in Asp.Net MVC`, I want to know that -
Is there any event available in `global.asax` OR in `base controller class` which calls only ONCE when form authentication happens. (I want to add something in session only once and only when form authentication happens)

I tried with `OnAuthorization`  and `AuthorizeCore` events of `AuthorizeAttribute` class.
Even I also tried with `Application_OnAuthenticateRequest` and `Application_AuthorizeRequest` events of `Global.asax` file..

BUT the issue is, all these events fires on every request and I want to execute somethings only once when `authentication` happens.

Could you please suggest me what is the best way to do this !?

**Note:** The authentication cookie is being set by another Asp.net MVC application which exist in same domain. (And I am accessing this application by submain - so I can access the auth cookie of parent application). BUT, when authentication happens to Application 1, I want to set some session variable in Application 2. (As my application 2 user is now authenticated and I want to add some information in session in application 2)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should have some action which does authntication. It shoud validate user credentials. What prevents you from adding code in this action?

Comment: Well, the authentication cookie is being set by another Asp.net MVC application which exist in same domain. (And I am accessing this application by submain - so I can access the auth cookie of parent application). BUT, when authentication happens to Application 1, I want to set some session variable in Application 2. (As my application 2 user is now authenticated and I want to add some information in session in application 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When authentication occurs in application 1, add an additional cookie that will trigger setting the session variable in application 2. In the `AuthorizeCore` override of an `AuthorizeAttribute` in application 2, check for the presence of the cookie. If it exists, set the session variable and remove it.

You might also consider adding the info to the user data portion of the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` instead of storing it in session.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is an application-specific event, and since the requirements and specifics of this can't be defined simply, there's no built-in event to handle this. So, you'll have to create this yourself.

Since you are using Forms Auth, you know exactly they authenticate, but I suspect you are interested in a way to communicate this to other modules or components in an loosely coupled, event-driven manner. I would suggest that you have a service interface defined in your business layer that represents your authentication service. You could then have your various components that need to notify (or be notified) of an authentication event talk to the authentication service directly, rather than try to push this through ASP.NET. My answer is rather vague because the info you've given about what you need to do in that event is not apparent.

For hell of it, we can consider how to push this through ASP.NET anyways. The class that is generated for your application, represented by Global.asax.cs, is like any class. You could conceivably add your own event to that class, and in `IHttpModule` (for example) that wish to subscribe to it, simply cast `HttpApplication context` parameter in the `Init` method to the specific type and attach the event as you normally would.

Comment: @Hacked- Please see my comments in Question! I have mentioned my requirement there !

Answer (score 0):

As you have found out, authentication executes on every request to verify whether or not the given user is allowed to view the given page. However, you will need to define a function somewhere which calls `.SetAuthCookie()` to authenticate the user (normally) on login. It is in this function where you should call your action.

Comment: Form authentication happens means- Authentication cookie is just set now and after immediate I want to add something in session variable, BUT I want my setting to session variable should call only once just after authentication happens! I don't want my setting to session code should execute on every request!!

Comment: Yes. You set the auth cookie only once per login, correct? I am talking here about **setting** the cookie, not verifying it.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no OnAuthorized event.  Perhaps there are in ASP.NET Forms, but in MVC things are little more manual and far more flexible.

If you are in a default ASP.NET MVC Internet application project, then open the `AccountController` in the \Controllers\ folder and find the `Login` method:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        // Add session data or trigger an event
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
```

You should find something similar to the above.  That is where you would add additional session data or any other one-time code you wish to execute when a user logs in.

The same concept applies even if you are not using the ASP.NET MVC Internet application.  At some point, you will need a controller to handle the login POST.  On a successful login is where you would execute your code.